# How to detect where a button release occurred

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to implement a fairly basic drag-and-drop to allow a user to click on a label and drag its text to another label.

I've got the button-down and drag stuff working nicely but I can't work out how to detect which label the drag finished at. I've bound to the  event for the target label, but when the binding fires, `%W` is the label where the button was initially pressed.

The following code illustrates the effect:

```
proc buttonRelease w {puts stdout ButtonRelease\ $w}
proc buttonPress w {puts stdout ButtonPress\ $w}
ttk::label .a -text a
ttk::label .b -text b
grid .a -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nsew -padx 30 -pady 15
grid .b -row 0 -column 1 -sticky nsew -padx 30 -pady 15
bind .a <ButtonPress> {buttonPress %W}
bind .b <ButtonPress> {buttonPress %W}
bind .a <ButtonRelease> {buttonRelease %W}
bind .b <ButtonRelease> {buttonRelease %W}
```

If I click on the "a", I see

```
ButtonPress .a
ButtonRelease .a
```

but if I drag from "a" to "b", I see the same thing. I'd like to see

```
ButtonPress .a
ButtonRelease .b
```

How do I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ButtonRelease>` event is always delivered to the widget that the corresponding `<ButtonPress>` event was delivered to; there's a grab done by the windowing system itself that enforces this. Instead, you need to get the global X/Y coordinates (`%X` and `%Y` substitutions in the event) and use `winfo containing` to determine what widget was at that place.

Comment: Thanks @DonalFellows. I assumed something like this was going on. I'd missed `winfo containing` when I was looking for something like that, so thank you for that too. In this case, I think I'll just pass the widget name to the bind script using `{buttonRelease .a}` etc. instead of trying to use `%W`.

Comment: Ah. Whoops. That doesn't work - even after binding `{ButtonRelease .a}` to .a, if I drag from .b to .a, the program outputs `ButtonRelease .b`, which I guess is what @DonalFellows was saying. I guess I'll have to do it "properly" with `winfo containing`. :blush: